# cannot print the value taken from socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;

    MyClientTask(String addr, int port) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String response = "";
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while ((response = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("response", response);
                publishProgress(response);
            }
            Log.i("response", response);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        Log.i("prama", values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

I write above code to read value from socket.when i start the async task the value will be print on the log as i do in doInbackground but my toast message will not be fired after the async task finished.

Comment: ...and how you start the async task?

Comment: MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask("192.168.1.33", 3000);
  myClientTask.execute();

Comment: this code only prints the only the 1 st log messsage appear in while loop.2 nd log message also will not be printed

Comment: `while ((response = stdIn.readLine()) != null)` is the problem ... program will be executed this loop until connection to the server will be shutted down ...

Comment: so how i avoid it.ok but if it is true wit should print the same log message again and again.but here that does not happen.it only print the response once.

Comment: react on special command to exit the loop ... or use onProgressUpdate to send information to the UI that new command arrived ...

Comment: i change the code i add the on progress.but it only print the response once.if while loop runs contentiously this will print something continuously bi dosenot happen